# How to add files name to a code with looping?

Tags: php, html, loops, for-loop, video

I want to add all files to a video playlist in a web page.

```
 $d = dir("G:\ARIFIN\Picture\s");

 while (($file = $d->read()) !== false){ 
   echo $file . "<br>";
 } 
 $d->close();
```

`echo $file` from the code above displays all files name in the folder:

```
aaaa.mp4
bbbb.mp4
cccc.mp4
dddd.mp4
```

I want to modify it to automatically generate output like below:

```
<figcaption>
     <a href="aaaa.mp4" class="currentvid">
     </a>
     <a href="bbbb.mp4">
     </a>
     <a href="cccc.mp4">
     </a>
     <a href="dddd.mp4">
     </a>
</figcaption>
```

But I don't know how. I am still new in programming.

Comment: Just change your 'echo' so it will display links insteand of normals text.

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution:

```
<figcaption>
<?php

$d = dir("G:\ARIFIN\Picture\s");

$first = true;
 while (($file = $d->read()) !== false){
    if ( $first ) {
        $first = false;
        $currentvid = ' class="currentvid"';
    } else {
        $currentvid = '';
    }
   echo '<a href="' . $file . '"' . $currentvid . '>' . $file . '</a><br />';
 } 
 $d->close(); 

?>
</figcaption>
```

Comment: it doesn't work.. It just played one video and then finished, not continue to the next video. anyway above the `<figcaption>` I had `<div id="video_container">
<video width="100%" controls poster="vid-rumah.jpg" autoplay>
<source src="dragon.mp4" type="video/webm"> <!-- webm-->
<source src="dragon.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>`

Comment: Automatically playing the next video, and echoing out a link are two entirely different problems good sir. I would recommend posting a separate question if this is the case.

Comment: Do you know how to echoing it like this: `<a href="aaaa.mp4" class="currentvid"></a>
<a href="bbbb.mp4"></a>
<a href="cccc.mp4"></a>
<a href="dddd.mp4"></a>` aaaa.mp4, bbbb.mp4, etc are from `$file`

Answer (score 0):

You can combine PHP and HTML easily.

```
<figcaption>
    <?php
     $d = dir("G:\ARIFIN\Picture\s");
     $count=0;
     while (($file = $d->read()) !== false){
         if($count==0)
             echo "<a href='{$file}' class='currentvid'/></a><br />";
         else
             echo "<a href='{$file}' ></a><br>";
         $count++;
     }
     $d->close();
    ?>
</figcaption>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $d = dir("G:\ARIFIN\Picture\s");
$str="<figcaption>";
$i=0;
 while (($file = $d->read()) !== false){ 
     $i++;
  // echo $file . "<br>";
   if($i==1){
    $str.="<a href='$file' class='currentvid'/>";
   }else{
        $str.="<a href='$file'/>";
   }
 } 
 $d->close(); 

$str.="<figcaption>";
echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: it doesn't work.. It just played one video and then finished, not continue to the next video. anyway above the `<figcaption>` I had `<div id="video_container">
<video width="100%" controls poster="vid-rumah.jpg" autoplay>
<source src="dragon.mp4" type="video/webm"> <!-- webm-->
<source src="dragon.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>`